# Chrome extension: console.log detector

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Does anybody know chrome extension, that helps detect `console.log` in javascripts on page?
If `console.log` call without checking, page crashed, and script not working. But i often put `console.log` for debugging, and sometimes i can forgot delete it.

Comment: have you tried `if(console) console.log("We can log!")`

Answer (score 4):

An easy fix is to always include a piece of javascript similar to this:

```
if (typeof(console) == "undefined") {
  console = {log: function() {}};
}
```

Comment: That's not what he is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Override console.log , and use your own function to debug.

```
function debug(d){ // debug function. console.log or alert
   if(off == 0){
    if(typeof(console) != 'undefined'){
        if(typeof(console.log) == 'function'){
            console.log(d);
        }
    }else{
        alert(d);
    }
  }
};
```

Set var Off = 0 , when you need to off validations.